# Sort an array of posts by distance

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps api with a WordPress project. I am using the a custom function to get the gooogle maps that are in bounds and displaying some information such as Name, address, distance, ID, etc.. The Distance is calculated by a `$_GET` variable and the googleapis distancematrix.

So I grab the ID's that are in the viewport(bounds) and use them in a query using `get_posts()` It looks like this

```
 $locations = ( $_GET['ids'] ) ? $_GET['ids'] : -1;

 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'location',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__in' => $locations,
);

 $posts = get_posts($args);
// etc, etc..
```

I need to sort these posts(locations) by distance but I am stuck on trying to figure out a way to do so. The address is stored in the posts post meta as a serialized array. Is it possible to evaluate and sort these posts before using the `foreach'?

Comment: fill array with distances - sort array

Comment: Where are the distances?

Comment: code looks incomplete, show the distances. you can unserialize an array using unserialize(). cant help u bud need more info.